# Import functions directly from Python 3 modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have the following folder structure for a Python 3 project where `vehicle.py` is the main script and the folder `stats` is treated as a package containing several modules:

[image]

The `cars` module defines the following functions:

```
def neon():
    print('Neon')
    print('mpg = 32')


def mustang():
    print('Mustang')
    print('mpg = 27')
```

Using Python 3, I can access the functions in each module from within `vehicle.py` as follows:

```
import stats.cars as c

c.mustang()
```

However, I would like to access the functions defined in each module directly, but I receive an error when doing this:

```
import stats as st

st.mustang()
# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'mustang'
```

I also tried placing an `__init__.py` file in the `stats` folder with the following code:

```
from cars import *
from trucks import *
```

but I still receive an error:

```
import stats as st

st.mustang()
# ImportError: No module named 'cars'
```

I'm trying to use the same approach as NumPy such as:

```
import numpy as np

np.arange(10)
# prints array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

How can I create a package like NumPy in Python 3 to access functions directly in modules?

Comment: The people saying `__init__.py` is mandatory to create a package haven't heard about [implicit namespace packages](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/) yet; those are why your current project structure doesn't raise an error on `import stats.cars as c`.

Comment: @user2357112 I'm aware of the implicit name space in Python 3, but it still doesn't take care of the error I'm seeing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Put an `__init__.py` file in the `stats` folder (as others have said), and put this in it:

```
from .cars import neon, mustang
from .trucks import truck_a, truck_b
```

Not so neat, but easier would be to use the `*` wildcard:

```
from .cars import *
from .trucks import *
```

This way, the `__init__.py` script does some importing for you, into its own namespace.

Now you can use functions/classes from the `neon`/`mustang` module directly after you import `stats`:

```
import stats as st
st.mustang()
```

Comment: I tried the `__init__.py` approach but I still get an error about the import not being seen.  Please see my updated question.

Comment: You need to specify a relative import: `from .cars import *`.

Comment: Yeah, this is Python 2-style implicit relative importing. You need the explicit `.cars` relative import.

Comment: ok, I needed the `.cars` import instead of just `cars`, the `from stats.cars import *` also works

Answer (score 0):

add empty `__init__.py` file in your stats folder and magic happens.

Comment: I tried the `__init__.py` approach and still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like
`from cars import stats as c`

You may also need a an empty `__init__.py` file in that directory.

```
host:~ lcerezo$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 18:05:06)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection as mys3
>>>
```

Comment: import stats.cars as c === from stats import cars as c

Answer (score 0):

You need to create **__init__.py** file in stats folder.

The **__init__.py** files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages. 
[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages)